# System.InvalidOperationException: No connection string named 'xxx' could be found in the application config file

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using EF 6 db first and asp,.net core web api. I found too stackoverflow post but no use.
The flow is WebAPI(Asp.net core)->BL->DAL(EDMX)

Comment: do you have a  `"ConnectionStrings": { "DefaultConnection": "xx" }` configuration  in your appsetttings.json  ?

Comment: Yes I have added

Comment: The flow is WebAPI(Asp.net core)->BL->DAL(EDMX)

Comment: Since the error information says `No connection string named 'xxx' could be found in the application config file` , you'd better post your appsettings.json file and output the configuration to log .

Comment: {
 "ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=Servername;Initial Catalog=dbname;user id=Userid;password=Pwd;"
 },
 "Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
   "Default": "Warning"
  }
 },
 "AllowedHosts": "*"

Comment: there's no `xxx` connection string except for `DefaultConnection`

Comment: Is `AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)` configured in your Startup?

Comment: No . Where to Add